# (Python): Moving average using 2D array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D list and I want to calculate the moving average along the columns numbers.
I have the following code.
Does anyone know a numpy method which returns a new 2D list with the moving average of all columns?

```
v = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

print((v[0][0]+v[1][0])/2)
```

#### Returns

2.5

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC and you have no problem using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

v = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

pd.DataFrame(v).rolling(3,axis=0, min_periods=1).mean().values
```

### Output:

```
array([[1. , 2. , 3. ],
       [2.5, 3.5, 4.5],
       [4. , 5. , 6. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you Juan.But I have a question, the first line in this array are my data or the heading of the data frame?

Comment: When I add `.values` I turn the dataframe back into a matrix, so there's no headers

Comment: Got it! def movAvgMatrixColumns(arr):
 rowNum, colNum = arr.shape
 res = np.zeros((rowNum - 1, colNum))
 for col in range(colNum):
  for row in range(rowNum - 1):
   res[row][col] = 0.5*(arr[row][col] + arr[row+1][col])
  
 return res